# How to create a movie screensaver in Windows

Tags: windows-7, movieclip, screensaver

Is it possible to make a Windows 7 screensaver out of a .avi movie?

I have created two brief movies (one 0:17, the other 1:14) . I searched for how to make screensavers, but can only find instructions for making a picture into a screensaver. I want to make a movie screensaver. Also, I am tech savvy, but not a Windows programmer, so I actually need a tool to do it for me.

Any help on how to make a screensaver from a movie?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Screensaver Maker, available [here](http://www.dd2002.com/).